# Java math help imaginary number

Tags: java, math

Im doing this math for my assignment where you have to find the imaginary number.

```
double dem = (b*b-4*a*c)*-1;
    double dem2 = Math.sqrt(dem);
    realPart = (-b/(2*a));
    imagine = (dem2)/(2*a);
    imagineneg = (dem2)/(2*a);
```

So basically Im trying to get it that the number inside the square root isnt negative. So lets say I enter `a: 1`, `b: -1`, `c: 4.25`. When you do the discriminant it would be `-16` but I want that to be positive so I multiple it by `-1` (thats the dem part). Then I sqaure root the whatever the answer is and then go to the imagine and imagineneg part where you find the imaginary number.

My problem is that instead of it being `-16*-1` to get `16`, some how I get `15`. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: ugh... wait... what?

Comment: Just to be sure: `(b*b-4*a*c)*-1` should be `(b*b-4*a*c)*(-1)`. You could also use [Math.abs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28double%29) to get the absolute value.

Comment: I tried it with your formula, I get 16. But anyway instead of multiplying by -1, why don't you use `-(b*b-4*a*c)`? Or maybe simply `4*a*c - b*b`? I think there are parts of the code you are not showing us or you're not revealing your true issue but jumping ahead.

Comment: Your bigger problem is that you're using an object oriented language and not even considering a Complex class.  Shame, that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.  Here's how it ought to look:

```
double root1 = 0.0;
double root2 = 0.0;
double discriminant = (b*b-4*a*c);
double denom = 2.0*a;
if (discriminant > 0.0) {
    double root1 = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant))/denom;
    double root2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/denom;
} else if (discriminant < 0.0) {
    // deal with complex conjugate roots here
} else {
    root2 = -b/denom;
}
```